# how to create an empty sql file on the server

Tags: php, file

I want to check if a file exists, and if not, I would like to create it. The file is a SQL file.

I've already got the code to check if it exists but I don't know how I can create it if it doesn't exist.

Comment: Hey. I'd suggest being a little more descriptive. Maybe adding some code. Tell us what you've tried and explain this with a little more clarity

Comment: Show the code you already have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creating a SQL file is the same as creating any other file.

```
$handle = fopen('myfile.sql', 'w');
fclose($handle);
```

See http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php

To check if it was successful you can then use [`file_exists`](http://www.php.net/file_exists).

If you want to write to the `$handle` use [`file_write`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fwrite.php).

Answer (score 1):

```
$filename = 'test.sql';

if (!file_exists($filename)) { file_put_contents($filename, NULL); }
```